# Android Listview is crashing on nonemulated Device

Tags: android, performance, listview

I have been programming a Listview, in which an Image as well as some Text is shown, while a new Item is created, when you press a button in the same xml. Emulating my App causes the Garbage Collector to "go crazy", and my App keeps skipping frames. As said in the title, it even crashes on an S3 (after taking a picture). Although I have been searching the web for possible improvements (ViewHolder) they just don't help or even cause bugs.

So here is my working MainActivity with the best improvements I got to work:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

List<FavImages> FavImages = new ArrayList<FavImages>();
ListView favImageListView;

Bitmap bitmap;

final Context context = this;

private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

//label logs
private static String logtag = "CameraApp";
//use main camera
private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

private Uri imageUri;
public Uri imagePath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.adrianopaulus/drawable/no_picture.png");
DataBaseHandler dbHandler;
int longClickedItemIndex;
ArrayAdapter<FavImages> favImagesAdapter;

private static final int EDIT = 0, DELETE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    favImageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();


    //enter an Item
    registerForContextMenu(favImageListView);
    //maybe without long
    favImageListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //position of Item
            longClickedItemIndex = position;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (dbHandler.getFavCount() != 0) {
        FavImages.addAll(dbHandler.getAllFav());
    }

    //List<FavImages> addableFavs = dbHandler.getAllFav();
    //if (!addableFavs.isEmpty())
        populateList();

    //Button Action
    Button cameraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
}

private OnClickListener cameraListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        takePhoto(v);
    }
};

//launch native camera app
private void takePhoto(View v){
    final Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

    //save Image and create file

    // in Progress
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.text_entry, null);
    final EditText input1 = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.pictureName);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //create Dialog
    alert
            .setTitle("Bitte bennenen Sie Ihr Bild!")
            .setView(textEntryView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Log.i("AlertDialog","TextEntry 1 Entered "+input1.getText().toString());
                            /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                            String inputText = input1.getText().toString();

                            mEditor.putString("pictureName", inputText);
                            mEditor.commit();

                            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), replaceChars(mPrefs.getString("pictureName", "picture")) + ".jpg");
                            //access information of file
                            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                            //save image path information
                            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

                            //for favImages
                            imagePath = imageUri;
                            mEditor.putString("picturePath", imagePath.toString());
                            mEditor.commit();
                            //
                            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

                            //
                            Log.e("Dateipfad", imagePath.toString());
                            FavImages favImages = new FavImages(dbHandler.getFavCount(), mPrefs.getString("pictureName", "Bild"), imagePath);
                            dbHandler.createFav(favImages);

                        }
                    });
    //show Dialog
    alert.show();


}

public String replaceChars (String inputText){
    inputText = inputText.replace("ä","ae");
    inputText = inputText.replace("ö","oe");
    inputText = inputText.replace("ü","ue");
    inputText = inputText.replace("ß","ss");

    return inputText;
}

//deal with output
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    //user hits ok button (picture accepted)
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        //Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
        //communication between apps
        getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);

        /*get Image
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
        //hold Image data
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        //get bitmap data
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            //set Image
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //notify user of success
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){ //catch exceptions along the way
            Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
        } */

        List<FavImages> addableFavs = dbHandler.getAllFav();
        int favCount = dbHandler.getFavCount();

        //for(int i = 0; i < favCount; i++){
        FavImages.add(addableFavs.get(favCount-1));

        if (!addableFavs.isEmpty())
            populateList();
    }
}

//
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Favorit bearbeiten");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Favorit löschen");
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case EDIT:
            //TODO: edit Favorite
            break;
        case DELETE:
            //delete Favorite
            dbHandler.deleteFav(FavImages.get(longClickedItemIndex));
            FavImages.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
            favImagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void populateList(){
    //ArrayAdapter<FavImages> adapter = new favImagesListAdapter();
    //favImageListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    favImagesAdapter = new favImagesListAdapter();
    favImageListView.setAdapter(favImagesAdapter);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView imageTextView;
    private ImageView favImageView;
}

//Constructor for List Items
private class favImagesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FavImages>{
    public favImagesListAdapter(){
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, FavImages);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        if (view == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        }

        FavImages currentFav = FavImages.get(position);

        TextView favName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.favName);
        favName.setText(currentFav.getImageName());
        ImageView ivFavsImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favImage);

        //hold Image data
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, currentFav.getImagePath());
            //set Image
            ivFavsImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (Exception e){ //catch exceptions along the way
            Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
        }

        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
   }

}
```

**Summarizing it:**
How can I make my App less memory intensive?

**Edit: parts of stacktrace from logcat**

```
    02-12 20:00:19.945      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten I/AlertDialog﹕ TextEntry 1 Entered b
    02-12 20:00:20.095      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten E/Dateipfad﹕ file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/b.jpg
    02-12 20:00:23.295      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    02-12 20:00:29.335      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1337K, 6% free 23771K/25287K, paused 31ms, total 49ms
    02-12 20:00:29.436      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1311K, 7% free 23693K/25287K, paused 31ms, total 48ms
    02-12 20:00:29.526      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1239K, 7% free 23686K/25287K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
    02-12 20:00:29.616      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1232K, 7% free 23687K/25287K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
    02-12 20:00:29.766      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    02-12 20:00:29.865      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1233K, 7% free 23687K/25287K, paused 97ms, total 101ms
    02-12 20:00:30.075      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1233K, 7% free 23690K/25287K, paused 35ms, total 38ms
    02-12 20:00:30.175      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 2% free 24895K/25287K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
    02-12 20:00:30.275      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 2% free 26099K/26503K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
    02-12 20:00:30.345      948-948/com.adrianopaulus.favoriten I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**Edit 2: new ListAdapter** :

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTextView;
    ImageView favImageView;
}

//Constructor for List Items
private class favImagesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FavImages>{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    public favImagesListAdapter(){
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, FavImages);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favName);
            holder.favImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        FavImages currentFav = FavImages.get(position);

        holder.imageTextView.setText(currentFav.getImageName());
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        try {
            holder.favImageView.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,   currentFav.getImagePath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Atleast post the stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: Ok just have to run the app again - one moment

Comment: There is no error in the Logcat you posted. Where is the "Crash"?

Comment: The crash happens on an Android Device, which is currently not available, the posted log, is from an emulated device.

Comment: If your title says "crash", post the stacktrace from the "crash"

Comment: As said sadly the test device is not available in the moment, but I wanted to give you at least something. Still the crashes are mostly where the emulator skips frames.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter is not adjusted for performance and is probably causing all the lag you're experiencing.

The things you need:

- Use of `convertViews` provided by the `getView` method, for proper caching
- Use of the `ViewHolder` pattern to avoid `findViewById` repetition.

All of this has been answered multiple times on SO already, however IMO the best source to learn this is still [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) by the Google's team.

Good luck!

Comment: Although I am following your tips it is still skipping frames etc.. As said I am taking a picture do I have to look out for special performance issue there.

Answer (score 0):

What can I advice you is try Caching your Bitmaps in internal Storage. like I did as follows.

ImageCacheHelper.

```
public class ImageCacheHelper {

    Context ctx;


    public ImageCacheHelper(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }


    public String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage,String fileName){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
         // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,fileName);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {           

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

       // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(String fileName)
    {

        try {
            ContextWrapper cw=new ContextWrapper(ctx);
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File myFile=new File(directory,fileName);

            InputStream istr=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
            Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
            return image;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

then in your getView method's

```
        @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null){.....}
            else {.....}

           Bitmap imageAnswer = new ImageCacheHelper(cContext)
    .loadImageFromStorage(cQuestions.get(position)
            .getImageUrl.toString());
    if(imageAnswer==null)
    imgDownloader.execute(tempView);
    else
        tempView.iView.setImageBitmap(imageAnswer);
    }
```

and in your AsyncTask object to get your bitmap

```
private class imageDownloader extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap> {

        ViewHolder v;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                and writing to storage


                    v = params[0];
                    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(params[0].ImageUrl)
                            .getContent();
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    new ImageCacheHelper(cContext).saveToInternalSorage(b,
                            cQuestions.get(params[0].position)
                                    .getImageId.toString()); 

   }
}
```

....

Hope I helped you my friend.